H-Bridge Brushed DC motor driving with 1 PWM input and 1 Rotation input
I am working on a project where i'm planning to drive a dc motor with H-Bridge driver using only 1 PWM signal and 1 Rotation digital signal. I have created schematics  which is down below.

In H-Bridge Driver Section, my question is does it work between VCC=24 to VCC=12. In the P-Channel mosfet that i use, max Vgs is +-20 so i used a voltage divider like 10k to 10k for drop the 24V to 12V to make Vgs=-12, and 12V to 6V to make Vgs=-6 which is higher than -2V to -4V.I guess that it won't work with VCC=5v because vgs going to be between -2V to -4V so it won't be higher than threshold.

In the schematic above, I created a logic driver to drive the H-Bridge control inputs with using only 1 PWM and 1 Rotation digital output.My question is that the circuit above is do the job correctly. In the left side, when i apply 3.3V to "ROT_PIN", i expected to connect 24V to "M_ROT_1" and also connect the "PWM_PIN" to "M_PWM_1". In the right side  when i apply 0V to "ROT_PIN", i expect to connect 24V to "M_ROT_2" and also "PWM_PIN" to connect "M_PWM_2". With that kind connection i expect to drive using only 1 pwm signal pin and 1 gpio to control rotation of the motor. Do you guys any idea that is this kind of approach will work? Or can you suggest any other solution because even though i'm not sure this works, it looks kinda complicated and a bad solution i guess.

Have you simulated your circuit? If not, why not? A PNP MOSFET is an oxymoron.

I did mistype, it's of course a P-Channel mosfet. I did simulation on LTSpice for the Drive logic section without including Q7 AND Q8. I read my expected values on M_ROT_1 and M_ROT_2.  I didn't simulate the H-Bridge because there is a lot of reference design for it. Only different things is the components. LTSpice is not an advanced simulator so i probably won't get a proper result on a component basis which the components that i used doesn't even exits in LTSpice.
